# Anything slider to go back to first slide after initial loop

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

like the title says, I'd like to go back to the first slide after looping through 4 slides.

I went through the options in jquery.anythingslider.js, but I couldn't figure how to implement this functionality.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but check out the FAQ page, listed under ["How do I get the slider to play through my slides, then return to the first one and stop?"](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/FAQ#wiki-restart), basically it needs this initialization code:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  stopAtEnd  : true,  // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will stop on the last page.
  onShowStop : function(e, slider){
    setTimeout(function(){
      // only go to the first page if the last page is visible
      if (slider.currentPage === slider.pages) { slider.gotoPage(1); }
    }, slider.options.delay);
  }
});
```

Please note: this code will always return the slider to the first panel, when on the last panel and the slide show stops.